# Is there a way to swap out the image associated with a ThreeJS mesh without having to destroy mesh object?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, three.js

I have a ThreeJS game that uses a set of cubes as the play pieces.  One face on each of the cube carries a custom image loaded via a specific JPG URL.  When the user starts a new game, I'd like to be able to just swap out the JPG image assigned to one face of each cube.  Is it possible to do that somehow?  Or do I have to completely tear down and rebuild each cube?  I'd like to avoid that of course because my web searching has led me to the conclusion that properly cleaning up a ThreeJS scene and the GPU resources it has encumbered is not a simple matter (including having to free up all references to any part of a mesh or it component pieces).

This code shows how I create the cubes:

```
function makeCardCube(cardImageUrl, textureBackSide, locX, locY, locZ, width, height) {
    let thickness = 0.01 * width;
    let cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(width, thickness, height);
    let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    let materialArray = [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('/images/cards/white-square-400x400.png') } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('/images/cards/white-square-400x400.png') } ),
        // Card face.
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load(cardImageUrl) } ),
        // Card back side.
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
            {
                map: textureBackSide
            }
        ),

        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('/images/cards/white-square-400x400.png') } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('/images/cards/white-square-400x400.png') } ),
    ];

    cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, materialArray );
    cube.position.set(locX, locY, locZ);
    // Flip the card 90 degrees "up" around the X axis so the card faces the camera.
    cube.rotateX(THREE.Math.degToRad(90));

    return cube;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to just swap out the JPG image assigned to one face of each cube.

You normally do this by creating a new instance of `Texture` and the assign it to `Material.map`. If you don't need the previous texture anymore, it's recommended to free the related memory by calling `Texture.dispose()`.

Here is a complete live example to illustrate the texture replacement.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 5;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
  
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var texture = loader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/crate.gif' );
  
    var material = [
         new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } ),
         new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } ),
         new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } ),
         new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } ),
         new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } ),
         new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } )
    ];

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // change the material of one cube side by replacing its texture
  
    setTimeout( () => {
  
         var newTexture = loader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/colors.png' );
         material[ 0 ].map = newTexture;
   
         // in this case we do not call dispose() because crate.gif is still used by five other sides of the cube 
  
    }, 1000 );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.js"></script>
```

`three.js R113`